# How do I find the orthogonal complement of this linearly independent subset $M=\{(a, b), (c, d)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that $M^{\perp}=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (x_1, x_2)\perp M\}$. I'm confused about what to do next and how to deal with the set being linearly independent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's start by taking an example.  Say we had $(a,b) = (0,1)$ and $(c,d) = (1,0)$. Then you want all the vectors that are perpendicular to both $(0,1)$ and to $(1,0)$; that is the orthogonal complement of $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$.  Do you know which vectors are in the orthogonal complement?

Comment: @MJD We have $\langle (x_1, x_2), (0, 1) \rangle = 0$ which means $x_1 \cdot 0 + x_2 \cdot 1 = 0$ which implies $x_2 = 0$, similarly $x_1 = 0$ from $(1, 0)$?

Comment: Exactly right! $(x_1, x_2)$ must be the zero vector. But the geometry should make this obvious: You want a vector that is perpendicular to both $(0,1)$ and to $(1,0)$, and this is impossible, except that the zero vector is perpendicular to every vector.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the facts
\begin{align*}
M^\perp &= (\operatorname{span}(M))^\perp, \\
(\mathbb{R}^2)^\perp &= \{0\},
\end{align*}
which are easy to proof.

Answer (score 0):

If the two vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then they span $\mathbb{R}^2$, so the orthogonal complement of $M$ is just the zero vector.

To see this, the fact that the two vectors span $\mathbb{R}^2$ means that every vector of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written in the form $\lambda_1(a,b) + \lambda_2(c,d)$ for some constants $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. Then the inner product of this vector with $(a,b)$ is $\lambda_1$, and the inner product with $(c,d)$ is $\lambda_2$.

Comment: Your second paragraph is only true if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are perpendicular.